# Can't reassign the value of a variable in Kotlin

Tags: loops, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and I am trying to write a function to convert a number to Roman Numerals; however, I am unable to set the values of "numberBeingChecked" and "romanNumeral" from inside the loop, would you know why?

```
fun encode(num: Int): String {

    var numberBeingChecked: Int = num
    var romanNumeral: String = ""

    myLoop@ while (numberBeingChecked > 0) {

        when (numberBeingChecked) {
            0 -> {
                return romanNumeral
            }

            in 1..4 -> {
                romanNumeral + "I"
                numberBeingChecked - 1
                break@myLoop
            }

           in 5..9 -> {
                romanNumeral + "V"
                numberBeingChecked - 5
                break@myLoop
            }

            in 10..49 -> {
                romanNumeral + "X"
                numberBeingChecked - 10
                break@myLoop
            }

            in 50..99 -> {
                romanNumeral + "L"
                numberBeingChecked - 50
                break@myLoop
            }

            in 100..499 -> {
                romanNumeral + "C"
                numberBeingChecked - 100
                break@myLoop
            }

            in 500..999 -> {
                romanNumeral + "D"
                numberBeingChecked - 500
                break@myLoop
            }

            else -> {
                romanNumeral + "M"
                numberBeingChecked - 1000
                break@myLoop
            }

        }
    }

    return romanNumeral
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    encode(0)
    encode(1)
    encode(21)
    encode(2008)
    encode(1666)
}
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong, your help will be appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really reassign these variables in your code. `numberBeingChecked - 5` expression does not decrease the value of `numberBeingChecked`. It just subtracts `5` from `numberBeingChecked` and does nothing with the result. To decrease `numberBeingChecked` by `5` you need to use `-=` operator: `numberBeingChecked -= 5`. Same applies to `romanNumeral`, e.g.: `romanNumeral += "V"`.

Another bug in your code is that you always break from the loop after the first step. You should only get out of the loop when `numberBeingChecked` is zero, so you really need to remove all these `break` instructions.

Additionally, you should avoid creating strings by concatenating multiple times, because it results in copying the whole string with each step. Instead, create a `StringBuilder`, append to it and at the last step invoke `toString()` on it to get a result.

The resulting code looks like this:

```
var numberBeingChecked: Int = num
var romanNumeral = StringBuilder()

while (numberBeingChecked > 0) {
    when (numberBeingChecked) {
        in 1..4 -> {
            romanNumeral.append("I")
            numberBeingChecked -= 1
        }

        ...
    }
}

return romanNumeral.toString()
```

We can simplify it even further with `buildString()` utility which helps us create the `StringBuilder` and convert it to a string:

```
var numberBeingChecked: Int = num

return buildString {
    while (numberBeingChecked > 0) {
        when (numberBeingChecked) {
            in 1..4 -> {
                append("I")
                numberBeingChecked -= 1
            }
            
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

However, the latter uses some advanced features of Kotlin, it is harder to explain/understand how it works internally and therefore it may not be the best for learning purposes.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the concept of StringBuilder and your answer was really helpful and descriptive, I know I am not supposed to leave a comment thanking someone but it really did help me.

Kind regards

Comment: `StringBuilder` is very common in Java and Kotlin. Kotlin partially replaced it with its string interpolation feature (which uses `StringBuilder` internally), but still, you can't code in any of these languages and not use string builders at least from time to time. The reason is that `String` is immutable and hence you can't really modify it in any way - you can only create an entirely new string. `StringBuilder` allows us to truly create a string from smaller parts, without creating multiple intermediate strings.

Answer (score 3):

You're not performing an assignment. You need either an equals sign as `i=i+1`, or a shorthand like `i++`.